# Does phpmyadmin have a function like access to split one tabe into multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, excel, phpmyadmin

I have an Excel spreedsheet with all my info saved in it. From the spreadsheet I save it as 2 CSV documents. The reason for saving it as 2 documents is because my host refuses to increase the upload size in phpmyadmin. I upload the documents into a table and use it from there. But this is not the correct way to use a database. If I import my Excel spreadsheet into MS Access there is a function that I can Split the table into multiple tables that have relations and ID's so that everything is only saved once linked very nicely. The function in Access is called 'Analyze Table' but the analyze table in phpmyadmin clearly isn't the same.

I have tried to build my own databse in excel and then export it to phpmyadmin but when trying to import data into my main table with all the relations it spits this message back to me 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails'.

What is the best way to import a large spreedsheet into phpmyadmin so it works like a proper database?

Please help as I'm at a dead end
Many Thanks